# How can I remove ESLint parsing error from @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, eslint

To transform a server view model to a json object I am using below code in the javascript section in a rasor view.

```
var jsonModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

The semicolon of the code is marked with a red squiggling line and the error 'ESLint encountered a parsing error' pops up (using VS 2017).

Surprisingly, when I build the project no errors show up. Also running the project locally and publishing it does not give errors and the page performs properly.

I have used syntax like:

```
var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

Then the ESLint error goes away, but I get syntax errors at other code parts.

Any hints as to what causes the ESLint error and how to remove it?

Thank your for your help. Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore the parser error. Its just razor not recognizing valid syntax.

When you quote the `@Html.Raw(...)`, you are converting the object to a `string` which is likely to be causing the other errors you have identified.

If you really want to avoid the parser error, you can quote it and then use `JSON.parse()` to convert it back to an object

```
var jsonModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
```

however that is unnecessary extra overhead.